# While loop is not working properly

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a while loop in my function for getting the values 1 by 1 but i am getting the only 1 value

```
while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($this->result))
    {
        $image=$this->getEventDetails($row['Album_top'],'Event_image');
        $alert.="<div class=facBox>
        <a href='gallery.php?id=$row[Id]' style=margin-top:0px;>
        <img src='admin/customer/eventgallery/$image' alt=''>
        </a>
        <div class=clear></div>
        <a href='gallery.php?id=$row[Id]' style=margin-top:0px;>$row[Album_title]</a>
                </div>";
    }
```

I am getting the image name from another function that is

```
    function getEventDetails($id,$fieldname)
{
    $get="Select * from sarnaevent where Id='$id'";
    $this->result=mysqli_query($this->con,$get);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($this->result);
    return $row[$fieldname];
}
```

Now i am getting the only value from the loop my $alert is having only one facbox. if i remove this line

```
$this->getEventDetails($row['Album_top'],'Event_image');
```

It works fine but i want this line to get the image name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `getEventDetails()`, you assign `$this->result`, overwriting the previous contents of `$this->result`.  Since that occurs inside the `while` loop where the previous result is being used, the loop exits because there are no further results to retrieve from the *inner* fetch.

User a different temporary result set inside teh `getEventDetails()` method.

```
function getEventDetails($id,$fieldname)
{
    $get="Select * from sarnaevent where Id='$id'";
    // Different variable name...
    $temporary_result = mysqli_query($this->con,$get);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($temporary_result);
    return $row[$fieldname];
}
```

In general, I would question the need to be storing a transient result resource into the object's `$this->result` for most purposes. In any case where you're using that inside a method, you are probably better off using a variable scoped only to the method, which lives only for the lifetime that result set is being used.

Please use caution when sending `$id` directly into the query. Although I suspect it is known to be an integer variable, and therefore it won't break the SQL, it's a good idea to get into the habit of using [`prepare()/execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent SQL injection.

One final point of caution: When placing the string variable into your HTML markup, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape it against malforming the HTML. (If the `Id` is known to be an integer, it isn't necessary there)

```
"...<a href='gallery.php?id=$row[Id]' style=margin-top:0px;>" . htmlspecialchars($row['Album_title']) . "</a>..."
```

Comment: even with this you may need to call $stmt->store_result(); to make sure you pull over all the results from the server or the second select command may kill the results coming from the first command. Or that is my experience.  YMMV.

Comment: @dboals With a prepared statement I think you're absolutely right. For regular nested calls to `mysqli_query()/mysqli_fetch_*()` I don't _think_ it's necessary, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: It worked i was having the issue of $this->result i changed it with your code and it works fine.... this time got something to learn ..... Thank you

Comment: @Michael Berkowski  yes for non-nested statements, my understanding is it can slow down the overall execution, but that may or may not be true depending on result set size. I only do this when I nest my statements.

Comment: @dboals Either way, a join query is generally preferable (and achievable) instead of nesting loops..;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mysqli_fetch_array()` try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` (see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php); the returned array will be associative (key-value pairs) where the keys are the column names.

Comment: Nop it wont work. It shows the same thing. When i put the value from the getEventDetails() than it creates the issue else it work.

Comment: By default, `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns both numeric and associative keys, so they're all present anyway.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski good to know, I had always been under the misconception that `mysqli_fetch_assoc` was the only way to get the associative array with columns names as the keys. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're blowing out your original query.

First, you do a query, and assign its result to `$this->result`.  You then iterate across those results.  For the first row, you immediately make a new query, *overwrite* `$this->result` with the new results, and then try to continue... but you've just replaced the rest of your results with the single result from the event details query, so `mysqli_fetch_array` doesn't find any more results.

Solution: use a separate variable for that result.  A local one should be fine, since you don't use it outside that function.  You may also need to use a separate connection; I'm not sure of that.  Try it with just changing `$this->result` in `getEventDetails()` to use something like `$eventResult` instead.